# Value from org.springframework.ui.Model to jQuery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to pass reCaptcha sitekey from my Spring MVC to thymeleaf template. I have an idea to reach this using jQuery `$("#reCaptcha").attr("data-sitekey", reCaptchaSiteKey);`, but can't find out how to get this value in jQuery.
Controller code `model.addAttribute("reCaptchaSiteKey", RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY);` Would appreciate your help to solve this problem in this way or any other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to go about this.  If you just want to use javascript, you can do javascript inlining:

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var key = [[${reCaptchaSiteKey}]];
    $("#reCaptcha").attr("data-sitekey", key);
</script>
```

You could also use thymeleaf to directly output the #reCaptcha div

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" th:attr="data-sitekey=${reCaptchaSiteKey}"></div>
```